# I attempted to follow a Brackeys FPS controller, but my player keeps orbiting around a fixed point when I try to look around. Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Movement Script as seen in Brackeys video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG5l0.png)
[Look Script as seen in Brackeys video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBpPR.png)

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend you just get the "Standard Assets" asset from the Unity Asset store. It's made by Unity themselves and it provides a great FPS controller that you can just drag and drop into your game. It also provides many other usefull assets that you can use in the future...

Comment: Thanks I'll do that